# What and how can we customize Android auto app?

Tags: media-player, android-auto

We are trying to understand developing an Android auto app with messaging and media functionality both. In the process of understanding all the guidelines provided by Google, have few queries,

1. Can we customize the media player action card icons?
2. How can we add more buttons in the action card? I understand maximum number options can be 8.
3. How to modify the color theme when the app is displayed in the head unit?

Please help in getting the answers for these queries.

Answer (score 1):

Android Auto is not letting you "cutomize" display or ui things for Media App.

But following my experience you can modify :

- Action icons (play/pause, next and previous) and adding custom
  actions and their position, except for play/pause/stop which always
  stand in the middle, prev and next on left and right.
- Color Theme of your app, which will modify only buttons color. Main
  theme is a Day/Night configuration by Auto.
- MediaBrowser items present in Drawer menu, their order, names, and
  icons.
- The current playing queue menu item, its visibility, label and content list.

Comment: Great help. I will learn more about the possibilities and comment back!